# Filter at any vars that match one of multiple conditions in R dplyr

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

i am doing titanic kaggle competition and got easy question. How to filter for the NA and empty values in any columns?
I know how to do it variable by variable, but want to put 2 conditions in filter statement. i got this so far:

```
na_count = titanic.full %>%
  filter_at(vars(-Survived), any_vars(is.na(.)) || . == "")
```

So what i really want to achieve is to vizualize on barplot how many NA or "" (empty) are there in each column, so later i can go imputing missing data.

thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To filter `NA` and empty values from selected columns you can use `filter_at` as :

```
library(dplyr)
titanic.full %>% filter_at(vars(-Survived), any_vars(is.na(.) | . == ""))
```

To count the number of `NA` or empty values in each column we can use `summarise_all`

```
titanic.full %>% summarise_all(~sum(is.na(.) | . == ""))

#  PassengerId Survived Pclass Name Sex Age SibSp Parch Ticket Fare Cabin Embarked
#1           0        0      0    0   0 177     0     0      0    0   687        2
```

Comment: Perfect, that what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we can use `rowSums`

```
nm1 <- setdiff(names(titanic.full), 'Survived')
titanic.full[rowSums(is.na(titanic.full[nm1])| titanic.full[nm1] == "") > 0,\
```